# PHP ltrim() function is giving a hard time

Tags: php, function, trim

I used the ltrim() function in php to trim ":new" from ":newname" but it is also trimming the "n" of name and returning "ame".

Here is the code :

```
<?php
echo ltrim(":newname",":new"); 
?>
```

Which returns

```
ame
```

Is there anything I can do ? Or any other function for the specefic task mentioned above ?

I already has tried using ":newName" instead of ":newname" but I can't do that every time I need to trim only ":new" and the string after ":new" can vary so can't do capitalizing the next letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the second argument is a character mask as stated in the [documenation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) - meaning that it strips all the characters defined in that string.

As a simple workaround you could use `preg_replace`:

```
<?php
$str = preg_replace('/^:new/', '', ':newname');
echo $str; // prints name
?>
```

Comment: Text after use: is not visible